# onInit callback of bootstrap switch to check initial state of element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, switch-statement

I need to check the current state of a particular bootstrap switch element on page-load and wanted to solve that with the onInit-Callback. Unfortunately it gives mit "undefined" when I ask for the current state. Here is my code so far...

```
$(".make-switch").bootstrapSwitch({
onText:'ja',
offText:'nein',
onColor:"success",
offColor:"warning",
indeterminate: true,
size:"big",
onInit:function(event,state)
    {
    var current_element=$(this).attr("id");
        if(current_element=="has-emotion")
        {

        alert(state); //gives me "undefined" for this and every other element


        }});
```

My Bootstrap-Switch Version is v3.3.2 and Jquery Version 2.1.4

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there an other way to check the state of the given element when loading the page?

Thank you very much!
Regards from Austria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like :

```
$('.make-switch').bootstrapSwitch({        
    onInit:function (event, state) {                        
        alert($(this).is(':checked'));
     }
});
```